# Extend generic class with additional generic parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-class

I have a generic base class:

```js
export class BaseSerializer<
  R extends boolean = false,
  M extends boolean = false,
> {
  readonly readonly: R;
  readonly many: M;

  constructor(options: { 
    readonly?: R, 
    many?: Many 
  } = {}) {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.readonly = options?.readonly || false;

    // @ts-ignore
    this.many = options?.many || false;
  }

  public fromDTO = (data: any): any => { return }
  public toDTO = (data: any): any => { return }
}
```

When I extend from it in a class without generics, it works as expected:

```js
export class DateField<
  R extends boolean = false,
  M extends boolean = false,
> extends BaseSerializer<R, M> {
  fromDTO = (data: any) => new Date(data)
  toDTO = (data: any) => new Date(data).toISOString()
}

const serializer = new DateField({ many: true })
typeof serializer.many // true
```

But when I extend into a class with additional generic, `BaseSerializer` generics assignment doesn't work and R/M generics get only their default values.

```js
export class EnumField<
  T extends any = any,
  R extends boolean = false,
  M extends boolean = false,
> extends BaseSerializer<R, M>{
  fromDTO = (data: any) => data as T
  toDTO = (data: any) => data as T
}

type T = "a" | "b" | "c"
const serializer = new EnumField<T>({ many: true, readonly: true });
// tsafe tests
assert<Equals<typeof serializer["readonly"], true>>() // Type 'false' does not satisfy the constraint 'true'
assert<Equals<typeof serializer["many"], true>>() // Type 'false' does not satisfy the constraint 'true'
```

Could you please suggest, how I can achieve behavior, when extended EnumField class returns T-generic value from its methods and in the same time `readonly` and `many` fields are properly settled?

Comment: Afaik TS can't handle this mix of I give you the first generic parameter and infer the rest from the passed arguments. Either it should infer all Generic types, or you have to pass all of them. And since you pass the first it doesn't infer the other two from the passed object but falls back on the default values. But I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: In such case the alternative is a little weird but I think it is preferable to manually setting every generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Thomas in the comments, partial type arguments inference is not a thing in TS. There is a long standing open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).

I don't know why it hasn't been implemented, maybe because default values for type parameters have been brought to the language about at the same time and there is some overlap between the 2 features and some collision in terms of API because writing `EnumField<T>` could either mean "infer the rest" (which would be very very handy) or "replace the rest with default values".

If a type parameter has a default value, there is now an ambiguity as to what to do and a sigil such as `EnumField<T, infer, infer>` would have to be used. That's a lot less appealing, especially given a user should not have to know how many generics the implementer is using (it doesn't need to be aligned with the number of arguments), so there may be discussions about enabling a rest syntax like `EnumField<T, ...infer>`, or maybe people want to add support for variadic type arguments and there is another collision there... it looks like a whole can of worms and nobody is touching it.

---

TL;DR as it stands you can either pass **no** type parameter or **every** required type parameter. And any type parameter which has a default value will not be inferred but replaced by its default value.

---

#### Workarounds

You can solve this with a factory function which has the first generic curried

```js
const createEnumField = <T>() =>
  <R extends boolean, M extends boolean>(options: { readonly?: R, many?: M}) =>
    new EnumField<T, R, M>(options);
    
const serializer = createEnumField<T>()({ many: true, readonly: true });
```

Another option would be to add an additional fake runtime parameter to the constructor or to the `options` object

```
const _ = null as any;

export class EnumField<
  T extends any = any,
  R extends boolean = false,
  M extends boolean = false,
> extends BaseSerializer<R, M> {
  fromDTO = (data: any) => data as T
  toDTO = (data: any) => data as T
  
  constructor(options: { readonly?: R, many?: M, returnType?: T} = {}) {
    super(options);
  }
}

type T = "a" | "b" | "c"

const serializer = new EnumField({ many: true, readonly: true, returnType: <T>_ })
```

---

I personally do not recommend structuring the code so that passing every type parameter is required, because in situations where the constructor arguments have been generated by a generic function or whatnot, it will not be easy for the user to supply type parameters that match the values. They can make mistakes by doing it manually or they may need/want to import some utility types to reconstruct the type arguments in a way that is synchronised to the generic function that produced the dynamic arguments.

Comment: That's an option, thanks! I prefer to keep the same interface for all fields if possible, so I started to think, mb it's easier to just pass all generics, like `new EnumField<T, true, true>()({ many: true, readonly: true });` to keep interface consistent, but factory is a good option. Let's see if there will be any other answers closer to what I want

Comment: I'll be happy to accept this answer, but could you please add to the beginning point, that in TS if one generic has been passed, other generics aren't inferred anymore, therefore the easiest solution is to just provide all generics like `new EnumField<T, true, true>()({ many: true, readonly: true });`, that's exactly the solution I took, because it's cleaner. Thanks for other solutions, I'm pretty sure they will be useful to consider.

Comment: I added more context and a little rant